# Installation Arduino IDE on xubuntu 16.04 cc.arduino.arduinoide.xml' does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, arduino-ide

When i tried to install arduino on linux Xubuntu 16.04, i have a problem executing the script install.sh because i got the next information

```
~/Downloads/arduino-1.8.2 $./install.sh

Adding desktop shortcut, menu item and file associations for Arduino IDE...xdg-mime: file '/pathdownloads/arduino-1.8.2/lib/cc.arduino.arduinoide.xml' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

For resolve this, i had to remove all about arduino using the next commands

1. Remove folder .arduino stored in /home/~/ if exists

   ```
   $sudo rm -R .arduino/
   ```
2. Remove the folder Arduino stored in /home/~/ if exists

   ```
   $sudo rm -R Arduino/
   ```
3. Copy  the folder arduino-1.8.2 to /opt

   ```
   $sudo cp -R arduino-1.8.2/ /opt/
   ```
4. Change directory to /opt/arduino-1.8.2

   ```
   $cd /opt/arduino-1.8.2
   ```
5. Edit the file install.sh and Change the line "RESOURCE_NAME=cc.arduino.arduinoide" to
   "RESOURCE_NAME=arduino-arduinoide"

   ```
   $sudo vim install.sh
   ```
6. Now run install.sh on /opt/arduino-1.8.2

   ```
   $./install.sh
   ```